# IEnumerable performs differently on Array vs List

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, ienumerator

This question is more of a "is my understanding accurate", and if not, please help me get my head around it. I have this bit of code to explain my question:

```
class Example
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

var wtf = new[] { "string1", "string2"};
IEnumerable<Example> transformed = wtf.Select(s => new Example { MyString = s });
IEnumerable<Example> transformedList = wtf.Select(s => new Example { MyString = s }).ToList();

foreach (var i in transformed)
    i.MyString = "somethingDifferent";

foreach (var i in transformedList)
    i.MyString = "somethingDifferent";

foreach(var i in transformed)
    Console.WriteLine(i.MyString);

foreach (var i in transformedList)
    Console.WriteLine(i.MyString);
```

It outputs:

```
string1
string2
somethingDifferent
somethingDifferent
```

Both **Select()** methods at first glance return **IEnumerable< Example>**. However, underlying types are **WhereSelectArrayIterator< string, Example>** and **List< Example >**.

This is where my sanity started to come into question. From my understanding the difference in output above is because of the way both underlying types implement the **GetEnumerator()** method.

Using [this handy website](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), I was able to (I think) track down the bit of code that was causing the difference.

```
class WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult> : Iterator<TResult>
{ }
```

Looking at that on *line 169* points me to **Iterator< TResult>**, since that's where it appears **GetEnumerator()** is called.

Starting on line 90 I see:

```
public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator() {
    if (threadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId && state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        return this;
    }
    Iterator<TSource> duplicate = Clone();
    duplicate.state = 1;
    return duplicate;
}
```

What I gather from that is when you enumerate over it, you're actually enumerating over a cloned source (as written in the WhereSelectArrayIterator class' Clone() method).

This will satisfy my need to understand for now, but as a bonus, if someone could help me figure out why ***this*** isn't returned the first time I enumerate over the data. From what I can tell, the ***state*** should = 0 the first pass. Unless, perhaps there is magic happening under the hood that is calling the same method from different threads.

### Update

At this point I'm thinking my 'findings' were a bit misleading (damn Clone method taking me down the wrong rabbit hole) and it was indeed due to deferred execution. I mistakenly thought that even though I deferred execution, once it was enumerated the first time it would store those values in my variable. I should have known better; after all I was using the *new* keyword in the *Select*. That said, it still did open my eyes to the idea that a particular class' *GetEnumerator()* implementation could still return a clone which would present a very similar problem. It just so happened that my problem was different.

### Update2

This is an example of what I ***thought*** my problem was. Thanks everyone for the information.

```
IEnumerable<Example> friendly = new FriendlyExamples();
IEnumerable<Example> notFriendly = new MeanExamples();

foreach (var example in friendly)
    example.MyString = "somethingDifferent";
foreach (var example in notFriendly)
    example.MyString = "somethingDifferent";

foreach (var example in friendly)
    Console.WriteLine(example.MyString);
foreach (var example in notFriendly)
    Console.WriteLine(example.MyString);

// somethingDifferent
// somethingDifferent
// string1
// string2
```

Supporting classes:

```
class Example
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public Example(Example example)
    {
        MyString = example.MyString;
    }
    public Example(string s)
    {
        MyString = s;
    }
}
class FriendlyExamples : IEnumerable<Example>
{
    Example[] wtf = new[] { new Example("string1"), new Example("string2") };

    public IEnumerator<Example> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return wtf.Cast<Example>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return wtf.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
class MeanExamples : IEnumerable<Example>
{
    Example[] wtf = new[] { new Example("string1"), new Example("string2") };

    public IEnumerator<Example> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return wtf.Select(e => new Example(e)).Cast<Example>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return wtf.Select(e => new Example(e)).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference is that transformed  is IEnumerable, weheras transformedList  is a list, because you are calling ToList() on the latter. While you can modify the values in the List, you can only enumerate over the IEnumerable.

Comment: because you have not 'enumerated' the first IEnumerable, when you iterate back through it again to print them out it will 're-enumerate' (run through the select statement again) the IEnumerable again and so will not have your changes.

Comment: If you want to compare array to list you need to slap a `ToArray` on the end of that first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq works by making each function return another IEnumerable that is typically a deferred processor. No actual execution occurs until an enumeration of the finally returned Ienumerable occurs. This allows for the create of efficient pipelines.

When you  do

```
var transformed = wtf.Select(s => new Example { MyString = s });
```

The select code has not actually executed yet. Only when you finally enumerate transformed will the select be done. ie here

```
foreach (var i in transformed)
    i.MyString = "somethingDifferent";
```

Note that if you do

```
foreach (var i in transformed)
    i.MyString = "somethingDifferent";
```

the pipeline will be executed again. Here thats is not a big deal but it can be huge if IO is involved.

this line

```
 var transformedList = wtf.Select(s => new Example { MyString = s }).ToList();
```

Is the same as

```
var transformedList = transformed.ToList();
```

The real eyeopener is to place debug statements or breakpoints inside a where or select to actually see the deferred pipeline execution

reading the implementation of linq is useful. here is select https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,5c652c53e80df013,references

Comment: Maybe something to add is that everytime `foreach (var i in transformed)` is executed, new `Example` objects are being created. On the first iteration the `MyString` properties are updated for those instances, but on the second iteration new `Example`s are created (and do not have these changes applied obviously). I think its something you've already said, but it makes it more explicit.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm after. I'm aware of the deferred execution and that by calling ToList() it will essentially force it to execute. The part I'm interested in is that when it's actually called, deferred or not, I *expected* it to have a reference back to the 'underlying' object. Thus, the first time it executes it wouldn't have one and it would evaluate the Select. Then second time I enumerated it, it would reference the same object. I.e. how List<T> operates.

Comment: Looking at it more, I'm starting to see it. I'm focused on the IEnumerable aspect.. when that's *potentially* not where the different functionality is coming from. That clone method may have sent me down the wrong rabbit hole.